# return the smallest possible join from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, concatenation

I have this code which works good for this array: ['45', '30', '50', '1'].

```
function penalty(a_list) {
  return a_list.sort((a, b) => a - b).join('');
}
```

for example: given that a_list is ['45', '30', '50', '1'] the smallest possible string will be '1304550' which is right, but what if a_list is ['32', '3'] given this current code I will get '332' which is not correct because '323' is the smallest possible string. Hope that helps.

Comment: So you want it to sort the array in some instances but not in others? What's the criteria for sorting?

Comment: return a string of the smallest value of the combined numbers in a_list

Comment: Do you mean you want the smallest possible int value out? Because I think for that you'd need to sort by the first character of the array item, then the second etc etc.

Comment: i've updated the question

Comment: You need an array of numbers if you want to sort by the size of the number not an array of strings. Or have your sorting parse the string into a number before comparison.

Answer (score 6):

You could take the concatinated values of `a` and `b` and the value of `b` and `a` and take the delta of it for sorting, which reflects the sort order of the two string for a smaller value for later joining.

If integers are supplied, then the values need to be converted to string in the sort callback.

```js
function sort(a, b) {
    return (a + b) - (b + a);
}

console.log([['45', '30', '50', '1'], ['32', '3']].map(a => a.sort(sort).join('')));
```

For a stable sort, you could move smaller values to top (which does not affect the later joined string). This sorts `'3'` before `'33'`.

```js
function sort(a, b) {
    return (a + b) - (b + a) || a - b;
}

console.log([['45', '30', '50', '1'], ['32', '3']].map(a => a.sort(sort).join('')));
```

Comment: @Mohammed, does this answer answers your question?